# Should I see a pattern in these IP addresses ?

Tags: wordpress, security, ip, administration

Recently, I have been putting a plugin on my Wordpress website to send me notifications about updates and logins.

There is a feature letting me know that people try to login as "Admin" and fail.

The thing is that all the IP addresses look a little bit the same and I have the possibility to block ranges of IP address.

I do not know how to spot patterns in IP addresses and wanted to know if anybody could tell me if there is a safe range to block from these addresses :

```
62.4.15.127

52.24.167.223

13.59.51.48

54.86.170.240

54.234.166.220

52.206.230.218

52.91.211.57

34.216.71.59

54.209.218.2

52.43.164.197

18.217.58.26

54.191.89.133

54.173.164.232

18.217.57.212

54.245.186.15

35.165.212.204

54.186.111.14

34.205.63.12

52.71.44.114

52.87.237.129
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear pattern in those IP addresses. Some of them are from Amazon Web Services, others from other hosts. You can lookup where an IP address is from using IP lookup tools (google "IP Lookup tools"). One such site currently is: https://www.iplocation.net

As for patterns, you want to learn about IP subnets and IP CIDR notation. The simplest pattern is looking at the third block 1.2.3.4 or number 3, if 1, 2 and 3 are the same, they generally belong to the same subnet class. If number 3 is similar and 1 and 2 are the same, they may belong to the same CIDR block. When 1, 2 and 3 are all different, they belong to separate subnets. Digital Oceans has a site with more details at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-ip-addresses-subnets-and-cidr-notation-for-networking

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is exactly what I wanted to know. I appreciate it !